# Android Get Phone SIM number

Tags: android

How can I get The SIM card number using code ??
I tried this code and it returned no number

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: have you added android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission in android manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = phoneManager.getLine1Number();
```

Needs READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr =
    (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String sDeviceID = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
    String sSimSerial = mTelephonyMgr.getSimSerialNumber(); 
String sSimlineNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Set the following permission

```
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in Android Manifest file
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not return the SIM Card Number !
it worked on the emulator but not on the device !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

TelephonyManager telphMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String simSerialNumber = telphMgr.getSimSerialNumber();

Ref :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimSerialNumber%28%29